# Find NotebookObject from a list

Tags: notebooks

I can create a new notebook, write to that notebook and then save the notebook with a new name. Having done this how do I now find the notebook object that corresponds to the one I have just saved? I can see the saved notebook in the list generated by Notebooks[] but how do I get the notebook object so that I could, for example write to it again or just close it?
The following creates a new notebook, writes some content and then saves it with a name.

```
nbNew = CreateNotebook[];
NotebookWrite[nbNew, Cell["New Notebook", "Subsection"]];
NotebookSave[nbNew, "new notebook v1.nb"];
```

If I type

```
Notebooks[]
```

I get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I now have a nice list of notebook objects with my new notebook somewhere in the list. Is there a way I can use Select with  Notebooks[] that would get the notebook object? Something like

```
nbSaved = Select[Notebooks[], ?? ]
```

Have I failed to find the code in Help or is it more difficult?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if I missed something, isn't `nbNew` still valid reference?

Comment: @kuba No I have missed the point. I am so used to programs having an output that I thought NotebookSave[...] would produce a new notebook object rather than just modify the existing notebook object. I should have checked... Thanks